# Load and show local JSON file in MVVM

Tags: android, json, file, mvvm, repository

I am new in `MVVM` structure. I want to make an application that has a local JSON file in `raw` folder and load data of it and show it on the screen.
I am confused, about how to load data in `MVVM` structure. I think, I should load data in the repository but I don't have `context` object there, and based on my search, it's not a good idea that pass `context` to the repository. I've searched a lot but unfortunately, I couldn't find related info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pass `Context` in a `Repository`, there is nothing wrong in it. What you should not do, is create the repository as a standalone class. Instead create an interface called `Repository` which will have a method to access the file and return the json String.

Then create a class called `RepositoryImpl` which can have a context in its constructor and extends the `Repository` interface. In most apps, the instances of the `RepositoryImpl` style classes are created using Dependancy injection frameworks like Dagger/Hilt/Koin and in a way context/context-depending objects are passed by injection arguments.

In a way this makes sure that your interface remains clean and abstract, while your implementation becomes Platform dependant and changing the implementation doesnt affect the code which uses it via interface. And the code also remains testable.